# Remap domain onto subdomain using bind

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, subdomain

I have a domain `internal.example.com` and a second domain `foo.bar.com`. Each of these domains has their own bind9 instance.

I would like to be able to access records in `foo.bar.com` using the subdomain `foo.internal.example.com`. ie I want the lookup `xx.foo.internal.example.com` to forward to the `foo.bar.com` DNS server as `xx.foo.bar.com`.

Is there a way to do this in bind9?

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you might be able to use the (otherwise rarely seen) DNAME record.

For instance, in the `internal.example.com` zone:

```
foo     IN      DNAME   foo.bar.com.
```

A query for `xx.foo.internal.example.com` would then return a synthesized CNAME pointing to `xx.foo.bar.com`.

Comment: I shall give this a try

Answer (score 0):

You can point both zones to the same zone file...

```
zone "foo.internal.example.com" {
  type master;
  file "foo.zone";
};
zone "foo.bar.com" {
  type master;
  file "foo.zone";
};
```

As long as you use the shorthand `@` and short hostnames like `host1 IN A 10.1.2.3` and not the FQDN such as `host1.foo.bar.com. IN A 10.1.2.3` in your zone file...